# Is there a way to use non-null assert operator and ES2015 Object shorthand syntax together?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a piece of code where I want to simultaneously use ES2015 **Object shorthand syntax** and Typescript 2.0 **non-null assertion operator**.

In the code below `item` is of type `number | undefined`. Right now I have to use the verbose syntax:

```js
const { item } = this.state;
this.props.onSubmit({
  item: item!
});
```

But I want to use something like:

```js
const { item } = this.state;
this.props.onSubmit({
  item!
});
```

Is there a way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Good catch. I'd suggest to [open an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues). If you do, please post the url as a comment.